# Why does "var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder" throw "System.NullReferenceException"

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, .net-core, system.data.sqlite

The following line in my c# code

*Line 202*: `var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder{DataSource = "localDB.db"};`

throws this error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Tel_Server.EchoSession.processDataPackage(DataPackage decoder, Byte[] buffer) in Program.cs:line 202

It doesn't happen every time, but I can't figure out which circumstances it throws the error.

My code receives a message then writes to a sqlite DB. I am receiving and writing many messages successfully. But occasionally I get the error above. It does not seem to be related to a particular message, as I have not done any processing by this point in the code.

Can anyone offer advice on how to debug?

Comment: Are you sure this exception is being thrown at "line 202"?

Comment: Is this the exact code with only one literal string value?  Or are there other variables that you used?

Comment: @C Perkins - The only thing different in my actual code is the file path is longer, it actually is in a subdirectory. But yes, it's just a literal hardcoded string value.

Comment: @dedecos - I am printing the exception using a try-catch block with ex.toString(). Is it possible the exception is outputting line 202 wrong? Edit: Ive recompiled and redeployed the code. Error is still showing line 202. Could it be giving the wrong line number still?

Comment: @Mark Nah I don't think so. Try changing `ex.ToString` to `ex.Message`, see if the message is different.

Comment: Or clear and then rebuild your solution. Sometime the references to the source are out of sync and you get wrong lines in the output.

Comment: The error is not in sync with the provided code. Do you have a `throw ex;` in a catch block somewhere?

Comment: @Henk Holterman - I do not have throw ex; anywhere. I have build> clean solution and re compiled by going build>publish. Seeing the same error and line number.

Comment: So, where is `Tel_Server.EchoSession.processDataPackage()` and have you debugged that?

Comment: @Henk Holterman - the line which is throwing the error is the first statement in "Tel_Server.EchoSession.processDataPackage()". I think it has to be an issue with the error not being in sync with the code - I am trying various methods to clean/rebuild/refresh.

Comment: What method threw the exception (check the `TargetSite` property)?

Comment: Over the past week I have made various changes to other parts of the application. Compiled/built/published several times. The error is still occurring on the same piece of code line 202

Comment: Line 202 is within a method called `processDataPackage` which is itself called by `Task.Run(() => processDataPackage(decoder, buffer));`